# Почему в Django при добавлении позиции в админке получаю - Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, django-admin, развертывание

Создал сайт на Django, локально всё работает. Выгрузили на сервер (выгружал не я), позиции не добавляются через админку, получаю ответ:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://turklek.com/admin/pharmacy/review/add/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view

Перерыл всё, вроде, у других были аналогичные ошибки, но решения их я не увидел. django.contrib.admin.options.add_view пофиксил - тоже не дало результата. Прошу помочь, около недели уже с этим торчу.[image: Структура каталогов][image: Страница с ошибкой]

[Основной urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DereJ.png)

[image: Настроки шаблонов]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скрине выделена pharma, ошибка относительно pharmacy. Нужна информация об именах шаблонов используемых в проекте и настройки для шаблонов.

Comment: @alex если правильно вас понял, то приложил к задаче скрины

Comment: а покажи еще pharmacy.urls. и класс который регистрирует модель pharmacy review. "django.contrib.admin.options.add_view пофиксил" что именно ты сделал?

Comment: @alex добавил двумя последними скринами. Это я с сервера скопировал себе на комп. Пофиксил - пытался отследить - где ломается конкретно, но принты не сработали.

Comment: так. погоди. а ты все миграции применил? и еще убедись что на сервере все миграции есть, что у тебя локально

Comment: @alex проверил - миграции применены и все присутствуют. Вчера обнаружил, что в virtualenv не была установлена библиотека pillow, установил, но проблема не решилась. Нагуглил, что такое связано с моделями, где есть ImageField